# JNI error when trying to run java code through cmd

Tags: java, cmd

After compiling any Java code, when I try run it from cmd I get this:

```bat
  Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have:

```bat
jdk-11.0.1
jre1.8.0_192
```

I also have `jdk/bin` in my `PATH` enviroment virable. Code runs fine when I use IDE and my PC recognizes `java/c -version` command.

Comment: If you have both jdk 11 and jre 8 installed, the command-line may be using the jr 8 jvm, which won't be able to run code compiled for jdk 11 ...  Have your cmd print the result of  "java -version" ?

Comment: yea when i hit java -version i get "java version "1.8.0_192". what wrong with jdk 11+ jre 8? what should i replace?

Answer (score 3):

`class file version 55.0` means this .class file [is compiled with JDK 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout). This file is allowed to run on Java 11 or above, but your `java` is using that `jre1.8.0_192`.

You should change your `JAVA_PATH` or `PATH` environment variable to make the command `java` points to a Java 11 version of `java`, for example that one located in your `jdk-11.0.1`, or use that `java.exe` inside your `jdk-11.0.1` to run this .class file.